# Excel: Replace text based on a substring of the text

Tags: excel

[image]

Column D contains the substring to look for, which could be anywhere in the search field of column A. Column E contains the value to replace the content of column A with. See the results in Column B. Can anyone help me out?

[After implementing suggested solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIO64.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a VB script to solve this:

```
Sub DetermineFeatures()
 Dim featureLabel As String


Dim testString As String
testString = "FEAT_EMV_L4, Team_1, Team_IBM"

Dim stringValue As Variant

Dim lookupRange As Range
Set lookupRange = Worksheets("LookupTable").Range("A1:B100")
Dim outputWorksheet As Worksheet
Set outputWorksheet = Worksheets("Output")


Dim feature As String

Dim rowIndex As Long

For Each cell In Worksheets("Original").Columns("O").Cells
    rowIndex = cell.Row
    cellValue = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell.Value)

    For Each stringValue In Split(cellValue, ",")
        If InStr(stringValue, "LABEL_") Then
            featureLabel = Trim(stringValue)

            ' Call the Vlookup function to look up the actual feature name 
for the supplied label. This
            ' returns the value from the second column of the range within 
the LookupTable worksheet.
            feature = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(featureLabel, 
 lookupRange, 2, False)

            outputWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1) = feature


            If Not IsEmpty(featureLabel) Then Exit For
        End If
    Next
 Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with it, I suggest a modification to the arrangement.

[image]

Arrange the lookup values as in the image, in `columns F, G and H` and the replace values in the next corresponding row. You would need 3 helper columns, (since you have 3 lookup values). `Column B, C and D` are helper columns.

Enter the below formula in `column B`, `B1`,

`=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&F$1&"*",$A1,0),F$2),"")`

Just drag it to the bottom throughout the range, and then drag it to right upto column E.

Column F is your actual output. Enter the formula in column F,

`=B1&C1&D1`

and drag it down. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hi @gowtham-shiva, I can't seem to get your formula to work. Excel says it's not valid. This however seems like a nice solution. Could you have a look at the formula once again?

Comment: @Antenne it works fine for me. Can you change the commas to semicolons and try once in the formula

Answer (score 0):

This works, but is not very elegant and won't easily scale.

`=CONCATENATE(REPT($E$1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$D$1&"*")),REPT($E$2,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$D$2&"*")),REPT($E$3,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$D$3&"*")))`
[image: Example Excel Formula]

It's series of `REPT(Replacement,COUNTIF(Values,*Labels*))`.  The `*`'s around the search allow it to be wildcard, essentially making the COUNTIF's flags of if the element is included or not.  We then repeat the replacement value the number of times the countif is present (which in the example will always be 1), and then concatenate the results.